# How to prevent anonymous (users that are not logged in) BugZilla access?

Tags: login, bugzilla

I have a BugZilla system, but it's exposed to the whole network - people don't have to log in in order to see the bugs (they cannot submit new ones or change, but they can see everything).

How do I make logging-in mandatory?

Comment: I honestly don't believe Bugzilla was design with that feature.

Comment: Editable user profiles and comprehensive email preferences
Comprehensive permissions system [source](http://www.bugzilla.org/)

Comment: @Sickest - could you elaborate? I don't understand your answer